# Trouble Animating a background Image

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to recreate a dribbble animation to improve my design skills. This particular animation confused me. After the bottom action sheet animated, the background image is being animated on the Y-Axis, but the animation is off compared to the original animation.

My Attempt

[image: TastyBurger]

Original Animation

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lI5W.gif):[image]

Link to the original Animation 
https://dribbble.com/shots/4038053-Tasty-Burger-App

My naive approach was to see if I pull off the animation by wrapping the ImageBackground Component in an Animated.View component and animating the yAxis using the spring function.
My Render looks like this

```
const animatedStyles = {
      transform: [{ translateY: this.state.yAxis }]
    };
<Animated.View style={animatedStyles}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={require('./assets/burger.png')}
          style={styles.ImageBackground}
          resizeMode="cover"
        >
        </ImageBackground>
</Animated.View>
```

And the code I use to animate is here:

```
openMenu = () => {
    this.setState({
      animatePanel: !this.state.animatePanel
    });
    this.state.animatePanel
      ? Animated.spring(this.state.yAxis, {
          toValue: -1,
          duration: 100,
          useNativeDriver: true
        }).start()
      : Animated.spring(this.state.yAxis, {
          toValue: -50,
          duration: 100,
          useNativeDriver: true
        }).start();
  };
```

I'm a beginner so if there are any tutorials that could help me solve this I would also accept that as the answer.

Comment: can you please post your styles

Comment: I quite like your animation actually. What is off?

Comment: The animation seems to be much smoother than mine.